# ¿Cómo enviar dos parámetros desde un botón para abrir un modal?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tengo un botón que me despliega un modal:

```
<button 
  type="button"  
  id="HistoricoAvisoPrivacidad" 
  name="HistoricoAvisoPrivacidad" 
  class="btn btn-success success btn-sm Aviso_Privacidad" 
  data-toggle="modal" 
  data-target="#modalAvisoPrivacidadHistorico,<?=$Id_Alumno?>,<?=$Id_Grupo_Solicitud?>"
  data-id_alumno="<?=$Id_Alumno?>" 
  data-id_grupo_solicitud="<?=$Id_Grupo_Solicitud?>" 
  title="HISTORICO"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ><br>Historico</span>
</button>
```

Necesito enviar los datos `id_alumno` y `id_grupo_solicitud` al archivo que hace la llamada al modal, el cual tiene una petición de consulta a la base de datos y lo que requiero es poner estos dos valores en dicha petición.

Esta es la línea para la consulta:

```
$resultadoGrupo_AvisoPrivacidadHistorico = $instanciaNegocioGrupo_AvisoPrivacidadHistorico->n_consulta_grupo_aviso_privacidadHistorico($Id_Alumno,$Id_Grupo_Solicitud);
```

Y lo que necesito es pasar los valores desde el botón a esta línea para que pueda realizar la consulta y mostrar los resultados en el modal.

Pero es lo que no puedo hacer: pasar estos valores.

Comment: Buen día, ¿tienes algún código Ajax incluido?

Comment: Si tengo un código de Ajax, pero supongo que para realizar esto tendría que cambiar del data-target por un onclick y poner una función que reciba los parámetros , para que al momento de hacer clic tome estos en el ajax y los mande al archivo , procese la consulta.  Probare haber si funciona.  Pero lo que no quiero es perder la llamada al modal.  Lo intentare haber si funciona.  Gracias

Comment: Usas bootstrap? que versión?

Comment: huy.. según yo estaba utilizando la 4, pero revisando algunos de los archivos js me señala  que es la v3.3.7... pero bueno

Comment: @Cesarin claro, puedes hacer eso, y en el `success` del Ajax abrirías recién el modal, prueba con la respuesta que te adjunté.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba creando una función que cuando se haga clic en tu botón `#HistoricoAvisoPrivacidad` se almacenen los valores de ambos atributos:

```
$('#HistoricoAvisoPrivacidad').click(function () {
  var idAlumno = $(this).data('id_alumno');
  var idGrupoSolicitud = $(this).data('id_grupo_solicitud');
});
```

Y en la petición Ajax, envías un objeto con ambos valores:

```
$('#HistoricoAvisoPrivacidad').click(function () {
  var idAlumno = $(this).data('id_alumno');
  var idGrupoSolicitud = $(this).data('id_grupo_solicitud');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'ruta/archivo.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      idAlumno: idAlumno,
      idGrupoSolicitud: idGrupoSolicitud
    },
    success: function (response) {
      // abres el modal
      $('#modalAvisoPrivacidadHistorico').modal('show');
    }
  });
});
```

Y ambos valores los recoges en PHP y los envías como parámetro de tu función:

```
$idAlumno = $_POST['idAlumno'];
$idGrupoSolicitud = $_POST['idGrupoSolicitud'];

$resultadoGrupo_AvisoPrivacidadHistorico = $instanciaNegocioGrupo_AvisoPrivacidadHistorico->n_consulta_grupo_aviso_privacidadHistorico($idAlumno,$idGrupoSolicitud);
```

Comment: Excelente, solo tuve que añadir la linea : $('#modalAvisoPrivacidadHistorico').modal('show'); de un Ajax que ya tenia, y me abre el modal, falta ver que me muestre el contenido de la consulta, como borre todo tengo que volver a generar la vista dentro del modal. Cuando tenga el resultado en pantalla lo confirmo.  Saludos

Answer (score 1):

También funcionaría de la siguiente forma:

```
<button 
  type="button"  
  id="HistoricoAvisoPrivacidad" 
  name="HistoricoAvisoPrivacidad" 
  class="btn btn-success success btn-sm Aviso_Privacidad" 
  data-toggle="modal" 
  data-target="#modalAvisoPrivacidadHistorico,<?=$Id_Alumno?>,<?=$Id_Grupo_Solicitud?>"
  data-id_alumno="<?=$Id_Alumno?>" 
  data-id_grupo_solicitud="<?=$Id_Grupo_Solicitud?>" 
  title="HISTORICO"
  onclick="nombre_function(<?=$Id_Alumno?>, <?=$Id_Grupo_Solicitud?>);"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ><br>Historico</span>
</button>
```

```
function nombre_function(idAlumno, idGrupoSolicitud) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ruta/archivo.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
      idAlumno: idAlumno,
      idGrupoSolicitud: idGrupoSolicitud
    },
    success: function (response) {
      // abres el modal
      $('#modalAvisoPrivacidadHistorico').modal('show');
    }
  });
}
```

Lo interesante de esto, es que se disparan ambos eventos, el llamado a la función y el llamado al modal mediante el atributo "data-target".

Comment: Buen día,  gracias por el aporte,  el modal funciona bien, solo que ahora tengo un problema extraño  no muestra el contenido y en el modal me aparece una leyenda: Notice: Undefined variable: _la_variable_ ,  cuando en el debug del firefox si muestra el resultado, pero en la pantalla no.  lo único que me falta por hacer es cambiar el nombre de la variable  a uno mas corto haber si funciona.